# Can I link to another page in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I'm creating a large document (text, not presentation) in Google Docs, and I want to be able to link to other pages in the same document (like a pdf or `#` in the url).  So far all I've found is how to link to a doc from an outside source.

If it is possible to link in this way?  If so, how?

Comment: Future questions like this should be directed to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - create Headings in your file and then a table of contents - if you hover over the table of contents you will see the links needed which you can also add manually.

The more general approach is to use *bookmarks* (see Insert->Bookmark)

Once you've created bookmarks you can then add links to bookmarks via Insert->Link...